# How to create a table in MYSQL based on a certain number

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a database where there is a **'n' number** of input from html and depending on that number the entry should go in to table column. For instance If a user select option as **'4' adult in party with one child**.The entry for that in table would go like this

> id : 1 | guestid:abc | adult:4 | child:1 |first name : xyz | lastname:xyz | contact: 123 | email: abc@gmail.com |

The problem here is though that i need to save details for every number of guest in this case its 4,the obvious way which i thought was to **keep incremanting adult in each row with a value of 1** but that would cause much redundant data in table and very hard to maintain.For instance it would look like this

> id : 1 | guestid:abc | adult:1 | child:1 |first name : xyz | lastname:xyz | contact: 123 | email: abc@gmail.com |
>
> id : 2 | guestid:abc | adult:2 | child:1 |first name : zxy |
>   lastname:zxy | contact: 123 | email: abc@gmail.com |
>
> id : 3| guestid:abc | adult:3 | child:1 |first name : lol |
>   lastname:lol | contact: 123 | email: abc@gmail.com |

As it is just not the case it can be any possible number **4,2 5,1** etc.What would be the best way to design a query to address this problem here

Comment: Don't store counts altogether. Just keep the details of each guest and query to get the counts if necessary.

Comment: @shmosel can you provide me with some query and table representation i am really not getting it

Comment: Table: `(id, guestid, isadult, firstname, lastname, contact, email)`, Query: `SELECT SUM(isadult = 1) AS Adults, SUM(isadulst = 0) AS Children FROM ...`

Answer (score 1):

You want a [master-detail relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface). Where common columns/values are in a *Master table* and the non-repeating column/values are in a *Detail table*.

In Master: id, guestid, child, contact, email,

In Detail: id, first name, last name

Also have a look into [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).